# Generate suggestion based on database (PHP and MySql)

Tags: php, mysql

Can you give me some tips how can i generate a suggestion based on the word entered by the user? Its not a misspelling thing, i wan't when a user enter the word: "hello" if the database does not contain the word "hello" but the word "helo" or "helol" suggest that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FYI**

You should look into PHP's [levenshtein](http://php.net/levenshtein) function, this finds closest matching words based on a score, using a dictionary file... I know you said it's not mispelling, but the dictionary file can be anything and you can have more than one, depending on how you want to use it

Answer (score 1):

It will be way too complex to do with MySQL alone. You need to index commonly used words using something like Sphinx Search (a stand-alone full text search engine) and then run the queries against Sphinx.

There is a pretty good thread about it at http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=5898

Comment: i don't want to use only mysql, i said in the title, PHP and MySql, but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Soundex function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.soundex.php) and compare submitted string to a dictionnary database, i.e.:

```
soundex("Hellllo")       == soundex("Hello");
```

All you have to do, is storing your suggestions soundex in a table. Then when a user submit a word, you can search for his soundex hash in your table and return the words with the same / close pronounciation.

The soundex method is kind of fast, but your dictionnary table has to be indexed if you need performance.